# what is the best way of giving the feedback to the user

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm using speech recognition and I want to show the users that when they click a button they should speak.

I was thinking about using a progress bar but i dont think its a good idea. Then i thought about putting a label saying whats going on.

Can someone suggest any more options. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vote for visual and/or audio feedback in the form of

- Popup/Notification box showing "Please speak into your microphone now" which fades away after a few seconds
- An image appearing such as [this one](http://thumb9.shutterstock.com.edgesuite.net/display_pic_with_logo/91368/91368,1249984163,12/stock-photo-speak-out-loud-d-public-sign-icon-35122627.jpg), visually suggesting you speak (possibly with a matching one suggesting now is not the time to speak)
- An audio tone, short and simple.  Get two tones though, one for "speak now" and one for "OK. you can stop speaking"

Possibly combine some of the above for dual feedback

Answer (score 2):

You could also use audio feedback. Something like:

"Speak clearly, if you speak at all; carve every word before you let it fall."

(Oliver Wendell Holmes)

Comment: +1 for cleverness... a pity that it would confuse your average user.

Answer (score 0):

I think that they clearest way to do this is to give them a pop-up with a stop recording button.  Also some kind of progress bar/time recorded seems useful to me too.  In general users like what they have experienced before.  Every user has used a simple tv remote or youtube progress bar.  My vote is for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the amazing replies. i was thinking about a messagebox too. AND thinking about putting a audible feed back too...